# Can someone explain me what those haproxy directives mean?

Tags: centos7, haproxy

I cannot find an easy answer for what "inter xs fall x rise x" directives mean.

Answer (score 2):

These are explained in the HAProxy ALOHA [documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/9-5/traffic-management/lb-layer7/health-checks/):

> `inter` parameter sets the interval between two consecutive health checks. If not specified, the default value is 2s.
>   `rise <count>`: number of consecutive valid health checks before considering the server as UP. Default value is 2
>   `fall`: number of consecutive invalid health checks before considering the server as DOWN. Default value is 3